# How can I recover from a timeout with Perl's WWW::Mechanize?

Tags: perl, www-mechanize

I'm using WWW::Mechanize to read a particular webpage in a loop that runs every few seconds. Occasionally, the 'GET' times out and the script stops running. How can I recover from one such timeout such that it continues the loop and tries the 'GET' the next time around?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `eval` :

```
eval {
    my $resp = $mech->get($url);
    $resp->is_success or die $resp->status_line;
    # your code
};

if ($@) {
    print "Recovered from a GET error\n";    
}
```

The `eval` block will catch any error while GETing the page.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to implement a method to handle timeout errors and hook it into the mech object at construction time as the `onerror` handler.  See [Constructor and Startup](http://search.cpan.org/dist/WWW-Mechanize/lib/WWW/Mechanize.pm#CONSTRUCTOR_AND_STARTUP) in the docs.

You could even ignore errors by setting a null error handler, for example:

```
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new( onerror => undef );
```

but I wouldn't recommend that - you'll just get weird problems later.

Answer (score 0):

This solution will continue to attempt to load the page until it works.

```
do {
    eval {
        $mech->get($url);
    };
} while ($@ ne '');
```

Answer (score 0):

For a more complete solution, you can use a module like Try::Tiny::Retry. It allows you to specify a code block to run, catches any errors, then retries that code block a configurable amount of time. The syntax is pretty clean.

```perl
use WWW::Mechanize();
use Try::Tiny::Retry ':all';

my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();
retry {
    $mech->get("https://stackoverflow.com/");
}
on_retry {
    warn("Failed. Retrying. Error was: $_");
}
delay {
    # max of 100 tries, sleeping 5 seconds between each failure
    return if $_[0] >= 100;
    sleep(11 * 1000 * 1000);
}; #don't forget this semicolon

# dump all the links found on the page
print join "\n", map {$_->text } $mech->links;
```